# How are page tables initialized?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I have been learning about virtual memory recently, and some questions were raised - especially regarding the initialization of all the structs.
assume x86 architecture, linux 2.4 (=> 2 level paging).

1. at the beginning,  what do the PGD's entries contain, if they dont point to any allocated Page Table?
2. same question for page tables - how are the entries initialized?
3. when process creates new memory area, say ,for virtual addresses 100 - 200, does it also create (if needed) and initialize the page tables that correspond to those addresses? or wait until there is an access for a specific address?
4. when page table entry needs to be initialized to physical address (say on write access) - how does OS select it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your goal to learn how to use virtual memory in e.g. your own operating system? Or learning in general? Because a lot can be said of the Linux kernel, but a great learning-tool it ain't! If you want to know about the Linux-kernel more specifically, then SO is not the right spot to ask, and I honestly don't know if there's anywhere good to ask that question. If it's more generally, then I suggest e.g. [the OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page), together with reading the code of other more accessible kernels.

Answer (score 0):

1. Entries have a valid bit. So if there are no page tables allocated in a page directory, all entries theoretically have the valid bit off and it wouldn't matter what else is in the entry.
2. Same as above, except I think if a page table is created that means a page from this range has been accessed so at least one entry will be set as valid upon page table initialization. Otherwise, there'd be no reason to create an empty page table at all and take up memory.
3. I'm interpreting your "creating new memory area" as using a malloc() call. Malloc is a way to ask the OS for memory and to map that memory to your virtual address space. That memory comes from your heap virtual memory range and I don't think you can guarantee the specific addresses the OS uses, just the size. If you use mmap I think you do have the ability to ask for specific addresses to be used, but in general you only want to do this for specific cases like shared memory.

   As for the page tables, I imagine that when the OS gets your memory during a malloc call, it will update your page table for you with the new mappings. If it doesn't during the malloc, then it will when you try to access the memory and it causes a page fault.
4. In Linux, the OS generally keeps track of a free list of pages so that it can easily grab memory without worrying about anyone else using it. My guess is the free list is initialized upon booting by communicating with the main memory controller/bitmap to know which spots of physical memory are in use, but maybe a hardware person can back this up.